# Split-apply on sequences

Tags: r

Every here and again I have the problem that I need to split a `data.frame` where one column is a (possibly unordered) sequence. The split shall be done at these rows where a certain criterion is fulfilled in the sequence.

So assume this data.frame as a simple example:

```
dt <- data.frame( A = sort(sample( 1:300, 100 )) , B = rnorm(100) )
```

I want to split `dt` whenever in `A` a gap larger 4 occurs and calculate the mean in `B`. What I do is to introduce an id-variable `F` by

```
dt[ , "F" ] <- c( 0, cumsum( diff( dt[, "A"] ) > 4) )
head(dt)

   A          B F
1  2 -0.8019945 0
2  6 -0.1948101 0
3  7  0.1961203 0
4 12 -0.2478185 1
5 13  1.2571841 1
6 14  2.1354909 1
```

and then

```
library(plyr)
ddply( dt, .(F), summarise,
   A.range = paste( range(A), collapse = "-" ),
   B.mean  = mean( B )
)

    F A.range      B.mean
1   0     2-7 -0.26689475
2   1   12-17  0.57051336
3   2   25-25  0.29054572
```

My question is: Is there no such function in `base` or other packages (`plyr`, `data.table`, `zoo`, ...) which replaces the `cumsum-diff` trick and gives me also more flexibility on the splitting criterion?

Comment: `rollapply` comes to mind, but even there you would still need the `cumsum`/`diff` trick.  Do you have a specific application where the tricks stop working / become too unwieldy?  Seems like a good solution here.

Comment: What do you mean by "more flexibility on the splitting criterion"? Your solution seems very flexible. I do similar stuff with logger data and you can encode almost anything with something like this.

Comment: @BrodieG not really, I was just surprised that I couldn't find something more specialized for such purposes. Other criteria could be, to open a gap (do a split) depending on the size of the gap, relative to the position in the sequence (e.g. 10% of the value of `A`) or depending on the gap size and how large the actual block is.

Comment: It seems like your solution would work equally well there (replace `4` with appropriate transformation of `A`, so I'm afraid I can't offer any insights.

Comment: This does not specifically address the `F` part but if your aim is to use base then this does it: `do.call("rbind", by(dt, dt$F, with, data.frame(A.range=paste(range(A),collapse="="),B.mean=mean(B))))` . Also you could replaced `dt$F` with the computation of `F` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing it the right way. To make it slightly more efficient (from a programming perspective), you can call the cumsum/diff [or other function] directly in the `ddply()` call

```
ddply( dt, .(F=c( 0, cumsum( diff( dt[, "A"] ) > 4) )), summarise,
   A.range = paste( range(A), collapse = "-" ),
   B.mean  = mean( B )
)
```

Comment: wow, I wasn't aware that this is possible, to put such an expression in `.()`.